# Singly Linked List: Removing

Tags: java, linked-list

Trying to write a method that removes all instances of a value from a singly linked list, but it doesn't appear to be working.

I tried to accomodate for whether or not the head contains the value, but I'm not sure whether or not this is the correct way to do so:

```
public void remove (int value)
{
    if (head.value == value)
    {
    head = head.next;
    count--;
    }
    IntegerNode temp=head;
    while (temp !=null)
    {
        if (temp.next != null)
        {
            if (temp.next.value == value)
            {
                temp.next = temp.next.next;
                count--;
            }
        }
        temp=temp.next;
    }
}
```

Is there something apparent wrong with my code?

Comment: what is the problem exacly, and why you are using count--

Comment: The count shows how many values are in the list.

Comment: put the if statement after the while loop

Comment: sorry, the edge case for removing the head

Comment: That didn't seem to solve anything.

Comment: The function your wrote it only removes the disignated node which holds the value the you are searching for

Answer (score 1):

Here the implementation of linked list with `add` and `remove` methods with test.

```
public class ListDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyList list = new MyList();
        list.addToEnd(1);
        list.addToEnd(2);
        list.addToEnd(3);

        list.removeByValue(2);
        list.removeByValue(3);
    }

}

class MyList {
    private IntegerNode head;
    private int count = 0;

    public void addToEnd(int value) {

        if(head == null) {
            head = new IntegerNode(value);
            count = 1;
            head.next = null;
            return;
        }
        IntegerNode current = head;
        while (current.next != null) {
            current = current.next;
        }
        IntegerNode node = new IntegerNode(value);
        node.next = null;

        count++;
        current.next = node;
    }

    public void removeByValue(int value) {
        if (count == 0) {
            return;
        } else if (count == 1) {
            if (head.value == value) {
                count = 0;
                head = null;
            }

        } else {
            IntegerNode current = this.head;
            IntegerNode next = current.next;
            while (next != null) {
                if (next.value == value) {
                    if (next.next == null) {
                        current.next = null;
                        count--;
                        return;
                    } else {
                        current.next = next.next;
                        count--;
                    }
                }
                next = next.next;
            }
        }
    }
}

class IntegerNode {
    IntegerNode(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    IntegerNode next;
    int value;
}
```

Comment: If I don't call add method, but call only remove the count throw NullPointer, because it can't initialized.

Comment: OK, I will take a look now

Comment: I added check for `count == 0` case.

Answer (score 0):

here is different ways to delete from Linked list

```
public Node removeAtFront()
    {
        Node returnedNode = null;

        if(rootNode !=null)
        {

            if(rootNode.next !=null)
            {
                Node pointer = rootNode;
                returnedNode = rootNode;
                pointer = null;
                rootNode = rootNode.next;
            }
            else
            {
                Node pointer = rootNode;
                returnedNode = rootNode;
                pointer = null;
                rootNode = rootNode.next;
                System.out.println("removing the last node");
            }
        }else
        {
            System.out.println("the linkedlist is empty");
        }

        return returnedNode;
    }

    public Node removeAtBack()
    {
        Node returnedNode = null;

        if(rootNode != null)
        {
            //Remove the commented line if you wish to keep 1 node as minimum in the linked list
            //if(rootNode.next !=null)
            //{
                Node pointer = new students();
                pointer = rootNode;

                while(pointer.next.next !=null)
                {
                    pointer=pointer.next;
                }

                returnedNode = pointer.next.next;
                pointer.next.next = null;
                pointer.next = null;
            //}
            //else
            //{
            //  System.out.println("cant remove the last node because its the root node");
            //}
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("the linkedlist is empty");
        }

        return returnedNode;
    }

    public Node removeNode(String name)
    {
        Node returnedNode = null;

        if(rootNode !=null)
        {
            Node pointer = new students();
            Node previous = new students();

            pointer = rootNode;


            while(pointer !=null)
            {
                if(pointer.name.equals(name))
                {
                    previous.next = pointer.next;
                    returnedNode = pointer;
                    pointer = null;

                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    previous = pointer;
                    pointer = pointer.next;
                }
            }

        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("the linkedlist is empty");
        }

        return returnedNode;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {

        return rootNode == null; 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to track where you have been in the list rather than where you are going. Like this:

```
public void remove (int value)
{
    IntegerNode current = head;

    while (current !=null)
    {
        if (current.value == value)
        {
            if (head == current)
            {
                head = current.next;
            }
            else
            {
                head.next = current.next;
            }
            count--;
        }
        current=current.next;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is "equals(current)" supposed to do exactly? would this compare the previous.value to the current.value and return true or false? I tried replacing this with "previous.value == current.value" and this did not work either. EDIT: Your exact code creates a nullpointerexception too.

Comment: @user3283585 You are correct. I was thinking about that and have changed it to object equality instead. Where exactly does it generate a npe?

Comment: Strangely, it seems to point to another area of my code altogether, my "get" command when it says "return temp.value;".

Comment: Was that because you were calling get in the equals? If so, the above method ought to now work. Also, bear in mind, this can/will leave the head member as null so you will need to have null checks in any other methods that use that member.